# "Sequence Contains No Matching Element" when calling DBSet.Add()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting the InvalidOperationException "Sequence Contains No Matching Element" thrown when trying to execute the following code. This is on initial set up of the database:

```
Global.migrationContext.SourceObjects.Add(sourceObject);
```

The source object looks like this:

```
DataMigrationMapping.SourceObject
  MigrationPasses   null                System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DataMigrationMapping.MigrationPass>
  Name              "COMP_CASE"         string
  Notes             "Complaint Case"    string
  Schema            "Wacka"             string
  SourceElements    null                System.Collections.Generic.List<DataMigrationMapping.SourceElement>
  SourceObjectID    0                   int
```

My dbContext looks like this:

```
public class MigrationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SourceObject> SourceObjects {get; set;} 
    public DbSet<SourceElement> SourceElements {get; set;}
    public DbSet<MigrationPass> MigrationPasses {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities {get; set;}

    public MigrationContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        SourceObjects.Load();
        SourceElements.Load();
        MigrationPasses.Load();
        Entities.Load();
    }
}
```

The error started appearing after I added this property to the MigrationPass class:

```
public Entity TargetEntity { get; set; }
```

Which leads to me believe there's something wrong with my model flowing from the Entity class. Possibly something to do with this class being abstract. The entity class looks like this:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public int EntityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EntityType EntityType { get; set; }
    public string RefCode { get; set; }
    public Cardinality Cardinality { get; set; }

    protected ObservableCollection<Field> fields;
    [NotMapped]
    public ObservableCollection<Field> Fields
    {
        get { return fields; }
    }
    public void AddField(Field field)
    {
        fields.Add(field);
    }

    protected ObservableCollection<Entity> roles;
    [NotMapped]
    public ObservableCollection<Entity> Roles
    {
        get { return roles; }
    }
    public void AddRole(Entity role)
    {
        roles.Add(role);
    }
```

Any ideas on what could be causing the error?

Comment: This kind of exception will be thrown when you are trying to select a value in a Linq query and that the enumerable does not contain values that match your criteria

Comment: Yeah that's where I'm used to seeing this error, but this situation doesn't seem to meet that criteria.